# Js: function and object scope /outside scope

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this

```
var Wheel = { //...function A, B etc.. here... }
```

how can I access an array value from a function A inside Wheel to the outside "root" of my javascript document?

PS. feel free to edit my title because i have no idea how to elaborate it. thanks

Comment: In your situation, can you pass in a reference to 'root' to your function?

Comment: Just to clarify your goal is to access an array from within function A at the root of your javascript

Answer (score 0):

define the array in the global scope

```
var myarray;
var Wheel = { 
    a: function(){
        myarray = [1]; //new array
    }
}

//then you can acces myarray anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the array a property of `Wheel`, eg

```
var Wheel = {
    arrayValue: [],
    A: function(a) {
        Wheel.arrayValue.push(a);
    }
}

Wheel.A(1);

Wheel.arrayValue; // [1]

Wheel.A(2);

Wheel.arrayValue; // [1,2]
```

Answer (score -1):

So from your representation, A is a function, which means that objects declared within it are lost at the end of execution, due to their scope. A would be called like this:

```
Wheel.A();
```

At which point A would begin to execute the function and any variables declared within the scope of A, which were preceded by var, would be lost at the end of the call.